# E-mail users on status change

Tags: add-on, email, status

I am looking for a way to e-mail entry authors on a status change of their entry when changed using safecracker. Any ideas?

I ran across MX Notify Control but that will not allow me to specify the entry author as the recipient to be notified.

Thanks

Comment: This is not really an answer, but I'm working on a notifications module that is capable of that type of notification. If you're interested in beta testing, drop me a line at support@intoeetive.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My add-on Postmaster is already available and by far the most comprehensive email solution for ExpressionEngine. It has a series of robust API's developers can extend to do really custom stuff. But it also includes UI's and plethora of options to send emails at just about any time without writing any code. v1.3 is in beta and brings a whole new Notifications API in the mix for cron notifications, among other things. I have over a year of development in this add-on and it's only going to continue to improve.

Postmaster even supports a huge variety of services like Mandrill, MailChimp, CampaignMonitor, SendGrid, MailGun, and more. I am adding new services all the time as people need them.

https://objectivehtml.com/articles/read/postmaster-v1.2

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will be spot on for my needs, thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if you run into any bugs or issue. You can post your support questions on SE or send them directly to support@objectivehtml.com.

Comment: Somehow I missed this your add-on. Looks really powerful, and even with the API! Do you have plans to add other than email types of notification (SM, IM, etc.)?

Comment: That's coming in a future update. I have a couple contract clients that need to post to Facebook and Twitter too, so I will likely just build those as a "Service". Including SMS and custom notifications was always a part of the plan, but I just use "email" now to define a scope to the add-on. Otherwise it's too abstract for average users to understand. POSTmaster implies it is the master of all things POSTed by forms.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [POSTMASTER](https://objectivehtml.com/articles/read/postmaster-v1.2) to create a trigger that would fire with any kind of change to the status or category of any channel. Using it even allows nice html emails if it strikes your fancy to keep things branded.